# Loading jquery-ui as requirejs module

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs

I'm using `require-jquery.js` and i'm trying to add `jquery-ui` to the mix.

If i use this definition on my main page i get jquery-ui properly:

```
// load main app
        require( { paths: {
            'jqueryui': 'cafe/lib/jqueryui',
            'ca': 'cafe/ca',
            'ko': 'cafe/lib/knockout/knockout',
            'komap': 'cafe/lib/knockout/knockout.mapping',
            'kopost': 'cafe/lib/knockout/knockout-postbox',
            'jd': 'cafe/lib/jaydata-1.2.5/jaydata',
            'jdKo': 'cafe/lib/jaydata-1.2.5/jaydatamodules/knockout',
            'jdDeferred': 'cafe/lib/jaydata-1.2.5/jaydatamodules/deferred',
        },
        waitSeconds: 60,
        shim: {
            'jd': { exports: '$data', deps: [ 'cafe/lib/jaydata-1.2.5/datajs-1.0.3' ] },
            'jdDeferred': { exports: '$data', deps: [ 'jd' ] },
        }
    }, [ 'jquery',  'ko', 'cafe/log', 'sp/app','jqueryui' ], function($, ko, log, app ) {
        //this logs the ui object properly
        console.log($.ui);

    } );
```

But when i try calling it from another module like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'ko','jqueryui'], function ($, ko)
```

I get an error from require.js : `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'match'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the configuration object in a separate `require.config` call:

```
require.config({
  paths : { ... }
});
```

See also [this page on RequireJS configuration.](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config)

Comment: Tried it, got the same result :(

Comment: Hmm just noticed that jquery isn't defined anywhere. Might that be the problem?

Comment: As i mention at the beginning of my question, i use require-jquery.js which already includes jquery as a module.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with a similar (but simpler: just require-jquery and jquery-ui) setup, although I do get bitten by caching issues. So if you want to make sure you're changes are picked up, try your browsers' Private Browsing/Incognito mode.